# WP Plugin for onpage link suggestions

Tags: plugins, links

I am searching for a good Wordpress plugin which suggests me relevant onpage links in my articles. The plugin from [here](http://wordpress.org/plugins/content-links/), I cannot handle as a noob and I think it does not what I want to.